# Error when using tabular environment

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a simple table, but it just won't compile.  Here's a sample bit of code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\Q{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{28pt}}l@{\hspace{28pt}}p{\widthof{$\Q^2$}}@{\hspace{5pt}}p{\widthof{$\Q^2$}}@{\hspace{5pt}}p{\widthof{$\Q^2$}}@{\hspace{5pt}}p{\widthof{$\Q^2$}}@{\hspace{5pt}}p{\widthof{$\Q^2$}}@{}}
$2$ & $1$  & $0$ &     &      &     &        \\
$3$ & $3$  & $0$ & $0$ & $0$  &     &        \\
$4$ & $6$  & $0$ & $0$ & $\Q$ & $0$ & $0$    \\
$5$ & $10$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$  & $0$ & $\Q$   \\
$6$ & $15$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$  & $0$ & $\Q^2$ \\
$7$ & $21$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$  & $0$ & $\Q$   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, I get a sequence of errors that look like the following:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.14 $2$ & $1$  & $
                   0$ &     &      &     &        \
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a length to store the value given by `\widthof`; here's your code with some modifications:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}}

\begin{document}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\widthof{$\Q^2$}}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{%
  >{$}l<{$}@{\hspace{28pt}}%
  >{$}l<{$}@{\hspace{28pt}}%
  >{$}p{\mylen}<{$}@{\hspace{5pt}}%
  >{$}p{\mylen}<{$}@{\hspace{5pt}}%
  >{$}p{\mylen}<{$}@{\hspace{5pt}}%
  >{$}p{\mylen}<{$}@{\hspace{5pt}}%
  >{$}p{\mylen}<{$}@{}%
}
2 & 1  & 0 &     &      &     &        \\
3 & 3  & 0 & 0 & 0  &     &        \\
4 & 6  & 0 & 0 & \Q & 0 & 0    \\
5 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q   \\
6 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q^2 \\
7 & 21 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. I used `>{$}...<{$}` to indicate math mode in the column format, so you don't have to explicitly use `$...$` in every cell.
2. Instead of using the `center` environment I used `\centering` to prevent adding undesired vertical space.

Comment: Great, this fixes it!  What exactly was going wrong?

Comment: @Thomas to be honest, I don't exactly understand why the `\inaccessible` message appeared here; this message usually indicates that a backslash was somewhere forgotten when defining a macro, but I don't see why it occurred here and,as far as I could track it, `\mathbb` was the culprit. I'll let you know if I can detect what the cause of the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

While a syntax such as `p{3cm-2\tabcolsep}` is allowed by the `calc` package, `\widthof` cannot be used there as it needs setting a box, an activity that LaTeX doesn't perform when building the alignment preamble: it requires typesetting, but at that moment LaTeX is only accumulating tokens for transforming the `tabular` specifications into what's understood by the lower level TeX instructions.

The right way is to precompute the width and store it in a register:

```
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newlength\qlen
```

(You gain nothing with `\ensuremath`, really.)

Then you can set the length in the vicinity of the table you want to build:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\settowidth{\qlen}{$\Q^{2}$}

$\begin{array}{
  *{2}{l@{\hspace{28pt}}}
  *{4}{p{\qlen}@{\hspace{5pt}}
  p{\qlen}
}
2 & 1  & 0 &   &    &   &      \\
3 & 3  & 0 & 0 & 0  &   &      \\
4 & 6  & 0 & 0 & \Q & 0 & 0    \\
5 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q   \\
6 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q^2 \\
7 & 21 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q   \\
\end{array}$

\end{table}
```

Using `array` rather than `tabular` frees you from all those `$` symbols.

Why setting `\qlen` there? Simple: you might decide to typeset the table in a different type size, so a fixed `\qlen` is not what you need.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to defining a length variable, say `\Qlen`, that'll store the value of the column width, your code can be simplified further by (i) setting the default amount of intercolumn whitespace to `5pt` (by setting `\tabcolsep` to 2.5pt), (ii) grouping the various column definitions, (iii) deleting most of the unneeded math mode specifiers in the table, and (iv) replacing the pair of `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` instructions with a single `\centering` macro.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, calc, array, booktabs}
\newcommand\Q{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}

\newlength\Qlen
\settowidth\Qlen{\ensuremath{\Q^2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} % set default intercolumn whitespace width to 5pt
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{l@{\hspace{28pt}}} % override default width
                *{5}{p{\Qlen}} @{}}
2 & 1  & 0 \\
3 & 3  & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
4 & 6  & 0 & 0 & \Q & 0 & 0    \\
5 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q   \\
6 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & $\Q^2$ \\
7 & 21 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \Q   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the intercolumn space is not always `5pt`. Also, the change to `\tabcolsep` should be made inside a group to keep it local.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- second point taken, will include it in the MWE. The first point, though, is not a problem: the MWE automatically takes care of setting the intercolumn spacing to non-default values.